# Keeping text from custom number format after change of decimal point to a comma with a formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I have source cells which a software extracts to an Excel table as numbers. Sometimes they have a letter flag attached to them and then they would appear in the table with the following custom number format: 0.0"q"

So it is either something like 1.4 or 3.5, or - when they have the flag - it is for example 2.2r or 0.4r

From it I want to generate a target table in which the cells have their decimal point changed to a comma so that the values there appear as 1,4 or 3,4 (when there is no flag), or respectively as 2,2r or 0,4r when the flag is there.

It does not matter what the format of the target table cells is (text, number etc.) but I have the following constraints:
- I should do this only with formulas
- I cannot change the format of the source cells

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? `SUBSTITUTE()`? Can you please post some sample input and expected output?

Comment: I tried REPLACE and SUBSTITUTE. With SUBSTITUTE(TEXT... function it seemed I was getting closer but I could still not make it.

Comment: Here is a sample input/output: [link] (https://imgur.com/a/YlJpnZr) Remember the cells with a letter flag are Custom formatted as 0.0"q"

Answer (score 1):

Say **A1** contains the numeric value 2.3 formatted like:

[image]

First enter the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function txet(r As Range) As String
    txet = r.Text
End Function
```

then in **B1** enter the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(txet(A1),".",",")
```

[image]

Comment: One of my constraints is formulas only - so no VBA macros.